# How do I handle this TypeError: Cannot read property 'uri' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, express, asynchronous

Good day house, please I am having the following error in my code in line 8 on the const uri = ...
It appears the uri const declared in line 8 is throwing error but I can't figure out what it is.

`(node:11524) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'uri' of undefined`

I have included the code below. Your response will be appreciated.

**THE FULL CODE**

```
class URIGenerator {
  getURI(controllerAction, params, id) {
    const caArray = controllerAction.split('_');
    const routeData = RoutesCollection[caArray[0]][caArray[1]];
    const uri = params ? this._bindParams(routeData.uri, params) : routeData.uri; //line 8
    return {
      id: id || routeData.action,
      method: routeData.method,
      uri,
    };
  }

  _bindParams(uri, params) {
    let match;
    let replacement;
    let uriParam = uri;
    const replacedParams = [];

    while (match = /:([\w_]+)\??/ig.exec(uriParam)) {
      replacement = params[match[1]].toString() || '';
      if (replacement === '') {
        uriParam = uriParam.replace(`/${match[0]}`, '');
      } else {
        uriParam = uriParam.replace(match[0], replacement);
        replacedParams.push(match[1]);
      }
    }

    const paramsForQueryString = {};
    Object.keys(params).forEach((p) => {
      if (!replacedParams.includes(p)) {
        paramsForQueryString[p] = params[p];
      }
    });

    if (Object.keys(paramsForQueryString).length > 0) {
      uriParam = `${uriParam}?${queryString.stringify(paramsForQueryString)}`;
    }

    return uriParam;
  }
}

module.exports = URIGenerator;
```

Comment: Perhaps you have given the incorrect arguments to your `getURI` method, especially the `controllerAction` session

Comment: i would assume routeData.uri is the error. You should check if your routeData object has the property uri.

Answer (score 0):

Error code is actually clear:

> Cannot read property 'uri' of undefined

You are trying to access .uri property on two places which are both "routeData.uri".

You defined it as:

> ```
> const routeData = RoutesCollection[caArray[0]][caArray[1]];
> ```

So probably RoutesCollection is the issue which is not included in the code.